# No rear clearance spring assisted lid hinge system

Tags: furniture, hinges

I'm building a bench/coatrack for my entryway, and I'd like the bench to have a flip top lid that stays open and possibly has a soft close (soft close not a deal breaker). I'd like the rear of the lid to be as close to the wall as possible, so I'm looking for a hinge system that will make the rear of the lid kick back as little as possible. Hinges like this will be a problem:

I'm thinking of using a system like this:

[image: https://www.thehardwarehut.com/images/cabinet_lid_stays/sug-nsdx-20.jpg]

Can I use this hinge for the spring assisted part instead of the one pictured?
[image: http://m.lowes.com/pd/Gatehouse-Gold-Cabinet-Lid-Support/3355536]

Also what kind of hinge is pictured in the solution I'm thinking of using (not the assisted hinge but the other one)? How much clearance will it need in back? Is there a better solution?

Thanks a million in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to use a lid stay, similar to the first link, then I would use a european stile cabinet hinge, which is what is shown in the picture as well.

I would recommend a soft close lid stay like this:
[image]
[Soft Close Lid Stay](http://www.rockler.com/soft-down-lid-support)

And a hinge like this:
[image]
[Blum Clip Top Hinge](http://www.rockler.com/blumreg-120deg-overlay-clip-top-3-way-face-frame-hinges-hinges)

This will allow you to open the top up against a wall, and this type of hinge should allow for up to an 11/16" overlay, so if you have a 3/4" box back, it will leave 1/16" reveal at the wall, and will not rub when opening.